# Compatibility of one operating system to another type

Tags: operating-system, 32bit-64bit, rtos

I was going through various resources and confused about some things, i tried to google but couldn't find some satisfying answers to this, hence posting it here.

1. Can a 32-bit OS be installed on 64-bit processor and vice-versa.
2. I have a 64-bit OS installed on my machine, now i try to install a 32-bit application, it throws an error regarding this 32-64 mismatch, so is it the OS which throws this error or application. I think application (correct me if i am wrong). Is there any specific reason behind this? Because i think 32 bit application should be compatible on 64 bit processor. Am i missing something.
3. Can i install an RTOS on my desktop? If yes, what performance impact i can see on my desktop relative to normal operating system, any specific type of applications?

Comment: with respect to your first questions there is already a good response in the stackflow pl. refer to the below link http://superuser.com/questions/9083/can-a-32-bit-os-run-in-a-64-bit-processor

Comment: For the 2 question, what is the operating system you are using, in your machine

Comment: This is a poorly formed question and off-topic for SO.  What are you trying to do?  Generally with an RTOS you choose it for a specific single application in an embedded system.  For desktop applications you are better of with a GPOS which schedules CPU time without concern to real-time deadlines.  With respect to 32 bit applications on a 64 bit OS that entirely depends on the OS - Win64 for example includes a 32 bit subsystem for 32 bit application support.  Regarding a 32 bot ON on a 64 bit processor, the depends on the processor and the OS.